# Redirect browser based on radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easier way to redirect the browser based on the selection from a radio button? This works but from what I'm reading on the world wide web there is probably an easier way.

This is my form:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="value" value="google"><span>Google</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="value" value="yahoo"><span>Yahoo</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="value" value="bing"><span>Bing</span>
```

This is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
$("input[name$='value']").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'google') {
        window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
    }
    else if (value == 'yahoo') {
        window.location.assign("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
    else if (value == 'bing') {
        window.location.assign("http://www.bing.com");
    }
});});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not put the web site address to the value directly and do `window.location = $(this).val();`.

Comment: Thanks Juhana, that worked. What if I wanted to add a submit button to this instead of the automatic redirect?

Comment: @brandozz You can get the value of the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) radio: `$('input[name$="value"]:checked')`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski once I have the value of the checked radio box how can I take that value and redirect the browser. I keep getting "?value=google&submit=Submit" tacked on to the end of my url when I submit my form

Comment: @brandozz [Prevent the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of the `<form>`'s [submit events](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), which is to redirect to `action` (current URL if you didn't specify one).

Comment: Just passing by. 4 answers and none accepted, so I was just asking my self if you did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would change the html just a bit to something like this:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://google.com"><span>Google</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://yahoo.com"><span>Yahoo</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://bing.com"><span>Bing</span>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
     window.location = $(this).val();
});
</script>
```

I would also change to the .on() method since it simply makes a call to .on() anyways. The reason is that .click() simply makes a call to the .on() method creating one extra function call that isn't really necessary. Plus .on() is much more flexible!

Comment: Can you please post any official documentation or link-to that provides the information that `.click()` method is deprecated

Comment: @roXon correction I was thinking of it .live() either way though .on() is still better than .click() since .click() just makes a call to the .on() method anyway.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ahalan/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function() {

    $("input[name$='value']").change(function() {
        window.location.assign("http://www."+ this.value +".com");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.replace` would be the way to go if you require a http redirect. However, if you wish to maintain history(functioning browser back button) then either of `window.location` or `window.location.href` will be your best bet.
If its a single page application, then you can also consider `window.location.hash` for hashed url change.

To get the value of radio button, you can try

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(e) {
   // preferred window location change appropriate as mentioned above
});
```

For a jquery based solution:

```
$('input[type=\'radio\']').on('change', function(e) {
   $(location).attr('href', this.value);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would set the url as the value of radio button.

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="websiteRadio" value="http://www.google.com"><span>Google</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="websiteRadio" value="http://www.yahoo.com"><span>Yahoo</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="websiteRadio" value="http://www.bing.com"><span>Bing</span>
</form>

$(document).ready(function()
 $("input[name='websiteRadio']").click(function() {        
    window.location = $(this).attr('value');
 });
});
```